# Check if method was called on EasyMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, easymock

Using EasyMock 3.2. In order to unit test an UI, I have to mock some dependencies. One of them is `Page`. Base class for UI tests looks like this:

```
abstract class AbstractUiTest {
    @Before
    public function setUpUiDependencies() {
        Page page = createNiceMock(Page.class);
        Ui.setCurrentPage(page);
    }
}
```

Most of the time I don't use the page explicity, it's just there not to throw NullPointerException when e.g. Ui calls `getPage().setTitle("sth")` etc.

However, in a few tests I want to explicity check if something has happend with the page, e.g.:

```
public class SomeTest extends AbstractUiTest {
    @Test
    public void testNotification() {
        // do something with UI that should cause notification
        assertNotificationHasBeenShown();
    }

    private void assertNotificationHasBeenShown() {
        Page page = Ui.getCurrentPage(); // this is my nice mock
        // HERE: verify somehow, that page.showNotification() has been called
    }
}
```

How to implement the assertion method? I would really want to implement it without recording behavior to the page, replaying and verifying it. My problem is a bit more complicated, but you should get the point.

Comment: You want to verify that a method on a mock has been called, but then state you don't want to use `expect()`, `replay()` or `verify()`. Those methods are used for the exact thing you want to achieve, why don't you want to use them? You understand with a nice mock, you'll only have to expect the call you're wanting to verify? You won't need rafts of expectations that you don't want to verify happened.

Comment: The reason why I don't like the `expect()`, `replay()`, `verify()` solution is that this code would be repeated in every test that expects a notification and this will introduce unwanted clutter (to clarify, there is three or four things to expect and replay in my real code). Even if I create some helper methods, I would have to remember to call them at the beginning of the test that verifies notification presence. That's why I have asked for a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I think that perhaps this is not really needed, since simply using *replay* and *verify* should check that the expected methods were actually called. But you said you want to do this without replaying and verifying. Can you explain why you have that requirement?

I think that you can use `andAnswer` and an `IAnswer`. You don't mention what the return value of `page.showNotification()` is. Assuming it returns a String, you could do this:

```
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import org.easymock.IAnswer;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SomeTest extends AbstractUiTest {
    @Test
    public void shouldCallShowNotification() {
        final AtomicBoolean showNotificationCalled = new AtomicBoolean();
        expect(page.showNotification()).andAnswer(new IAnswer<String>() {
            @Override
            public String answer() {
                showNotificationCalled.set(true);
                return "";
            }
        });

        replay(page);
        Ui.getCurrentPage();
        verify(page);

        assertTrue("showNotification not called", showNotificationCalled.get());
    }
}
```

If showNotification returns void, I believe you would need to do this:

```
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expectLastCall;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import org.easymock.IAnswer;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SomeTest extends AbstractUiTest {
    @Test
    public void shouldCallShowNotification() {
        final AtomicBoolean showNotificationCalled = new AtomicBoolean();
        page.showNotification();
        expectLastCall().andAnswer(new IAnswer<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void answer() {
                showNotificationCalled.set(true);
                return null;
            }
        });

        replay(page);
        Ui.getCurrentPage();
        verify(page);

        assertTrue("showNotification not called", showNotificationCalled.get());
    }
}
```

Note: I've used an `AtomicBoolean` to record whether the method was called. You could also use a boolean array of a single element, or your own mutable object. I used `AtomicBoolean` not for its concurrency properties, but simply because it is a handy mutable boolean object that is already present in the Java standard libraries.

The other thing that I have done to verify that a method was being called is to not use a mock at all, but to create an instance of Page as an anonymous inner class and override the showNotification method, and record somewhere that the call occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Use a nice mock in the tests where you don't care what happens to page and a normal mock in those tests where you want to test something explicit - and use expect, verify etc. I.e. have two variables in your setup method: nicePage (acts as a stub) and mockPage (acts as a mock)